# Make active hyperlinks opaque and others transparent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to give some style to my active hyperlink in navigation by making the active one opaque and others transparent.

The `opacity` value and other styles are exactly the same with my hover styling. When I hover on the hyperlinks the hovered element becomes opaque and the others become transparent. I want exactly the same thing for the active hyperlink, but I don't know why it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header-nav ul li').on('click', '#header-nav ul li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
#header-nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: var(--our-dark-color);
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffb3, #ffff66, #ffff00, #b3b300);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .4s ease-out;
  animation: nav-load var(--nav-load-time) ease-in;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#header-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .4s ease-out;
  animation-name: nav-link-load;
  animation-duration: var(--nav-link-load-time);
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: scale(0);
}

#header-nav ul li.active {
  opacity: .5;
}

nav .mainMenu li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--our-dark-color);
  padding: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#header-nav:hover li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: .5;
}

@keyframes nav-link-load {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav id="header-nav">
        <ul class="mainMenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="#Home" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#AboutMe" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Skills" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Resume" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Comment" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've set `transform: scale(0);` on the `li` so they're not visible...?

Comment: If something is active, and you're hovering on another ```li```, do you want the active one to lose opacity? Or will the active one be opaque and whatever is being hovered over will be opaque?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh sorry. i forgot to mention some other related parts of my codes. they're actually going to be shown by means of animation. i edited my codes.

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui well actually i want the one which has been hovered and also the active one be opaque at the same time but others be transparent.

Comment: @Matin Okay cool, so I've done that in my snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the `transform: scale` to 1.

Your issue came from the way you set up the eventListener.

This is what you've written:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header-nav ul li').on('click', '#header-nav ul li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

What you need is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header-nav ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

I removed the parameter that you entered after *'click'*, since you don't need it. You've already specified the element that you want to add the eventListener to at the beginning of the line.

I've also changed the CSS a bit to keep both the `active` element opaque, and the element being hovered over. If you don't want this, you don't need to make any changes to your CSS. Just fix the JS statement.

Here's a snippet of the changes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header-nav ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
#header-nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: var(--our-dark-color);
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffb3, #ffff66, #ffff00, #b3b300);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .4s ease-out;
  animation: nav-load var(--nav-load-time) ease-in;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#header-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .4s ease-out;
  animation-name: nav-link-load;
  animation-duration: var(--nav-link-load-time);
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 0.5;
}


#header-nav ul li.active {
  opacity: 1; //This has been modified
}

nav .mainMenu li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--our-dark-color);
  padding: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}


#header-nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1; //This is new
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav id="header-nav">
        <ul class="mainMenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="#Home" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#AboutMe" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Skills" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Resume" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Comment" class="nav-item">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```